# Grunt Node and Express Local Dev HTTPS Certificates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, ssl

I'm trying to make a start at Service Workers and read you require to have an ssl cert.

I've Got an AngularJS 1.x application and a Node Express back end, and I run both independently so I I use `grunt serve` to run the front end on port `8443` and I use `node app.js` to run express which is on `7443`.

> note: I'm doing this on macOS

I used the guide on how to set up https on a project that uses Grunt: [here](https://www.gilluminate.com/2014/06/10/livereload-ssl-https-grunt-watch/)

> openssl genrsa -out livereload.key 1024
>
> openssl req -new -key livereload.key -out livereload.csr
>
> openssl x509 -req -in livereload.csr -signkey livereload.key -out livereload.crt

**Gruntfile.js**

```
options: {
    protocol: 'https', // or 'http2'
    port: 8443,
    hostname: '0.0.0.0',
    key: grunt.file.read('livereload.key'),
    cert: grunt.file.read('livereload.crt')
},
```

**node app.js**

```
var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('../livereload.key', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('../livereload.crt', 'utf8');
var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};

httpsServer.listen(7443, config.ip, function () {
  console.log('Express server listening on %d, in %s mode', 7443, app.get('env'));
});
```

Both start with no errors, the front end does complain the connection is not private. When my front end tried to hit an endpoint on the express server I receive the following;

> OPTIONS https://localhost:7443/api/census/general net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Could someone please assist on this problem of mine.

Comment: Do you know what the expiration date is on the `livereload.crt` file? If not, you can run:

`openssl x509 -in livereload.crt -text -noout`. Also, did you remember to configure your server to serve the `livereload.crt` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created a self-signed certificate, which is fine for development and testing but is considered *unsafe* for general use.  Unlike SSL certificates purchased from reputable third-parties, self-signed certificates are untrusted by default.

You will need to tell your OS to explicitly trust the certificate.  I'm unfamiliar with Mac OS but [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/404178/importing-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-on-macos) was previously answered on SuperUser.